# Hide select in a form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I want to hide this `select`:

```
<select id="point" name="point" size="1">
    <option value="10">10 (Recommandé)</option> 
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option> 
    <option value="7">7</option> 
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery('#point').hide();
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Your original post did not have an id on the select, you updated it with the id. Does your actual code have the id="point"? Also, is jQuery loaded, and is that jQuery statement inside of a document ready function?

Comment: any errors in your browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

Hide it after it is being loaded in the page. You can use the following jQuery code to do so.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#point").hide();
});
```

Also check if you include the **jquery** file in the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code as you have it hear.  Your issue may be in how you are invoking the code.  Use `document.ready` to ensure the DOM has loaded.

See the following plunkr of your code working.

`jQuery('#point').hide();`

https://plnkr.co/edit/Lmn7O4?p=preview